# how to open smartphone default web browser app using QRcode deep linking

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, deep-linking

I am generating a QRcode which contain web link

So when anyone scans the QR code from any application weather from **IOS** or **Android**

Can we open that QRCode URL directs into smartphone's default web browser?

I have tried it through Deep linking but each and every scanner application only showing the scan result, however, I am not able to open WEB Browser

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if it's from a QR Code or not.
Get the string in the QR Code, check if it's a valid URL and start a new intent.

> ```
> public void openWebPage(String url) {
>     Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
>     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
>     if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
>         startActivity(intent);
>     }
> }
> ```

See [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser)

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can mark an Intent after scanning QRCode from device

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Must check link is correct or not.

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
```

Answer (score 0):

First on onActivityResult of your QR Code scanning, you can check either result is a valid URL.
If the is a valid URL, start your Intent to show your default Browser with that link.